# Best way to download data from Wordpress website

Tags: objective-c, wordpress, ios

I want to write an iOS app that must download data from a website using Wordpress as content managment system. What' s the best way to do this? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What kind of data ?
If this is post, page , comment you should use XML-RPC : http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_wp

Comment: I need to download a list of POI stored in the Wordpress Database.

Comment: A remote connection to the database is not possible ?

Comment: I don't know at the moment. maybe yes or maybe not!

Answer (score 1):

Uhm, one solution is to use the wordpress export function (wp-admin/export.php). It gives to you an XML file that you can parse.

After you are logged into the account, you can issue a simple get. Or, you can download your posts/pages via XML-RPC, as already noted!http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_wp

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I will do some research to see if I can travel this road